# USB 3 spontaniously stopped working on reboot

Tags: arch-linux, usb

I'm running 4.13.3-1-ARCH and I have verified that the offending USB 3 ports still work in other Operating Systems. For clarification, I have a H81M-E34 motherboard and it's the I/O shield USB3 ports which aren't working anymore. The Front I/O still work.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 413c:a503 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. RDF8
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xfs                  1048576  0
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
crc32c_generic         16384  0
jfs                   180224  0
btrfs                1036288  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
cfg80211              532480  0
rfkill                 20480  3 cfg80211
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_usb_audio         163840  2
mousedev               20480  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        28672  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
input_leds             16384  0
led_class              16384  1 input_leds
joydev                 20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxdrv               385024  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
nvidia              10526720  156
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
vfat                   20480  1
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
fat                    65536  1 vfat
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             192512  0
kvm                   516096  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77824  1
aesni_intel           184320  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
evdev                  24576  10
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
mac_hid                16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
fuse                   94208  7
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_codec         106496  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
drm                   303104  3 nvidia
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm                86016  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
pcspkr                 16384  0
i2c_i801               24576  0
r8169                  77824  0
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
mii                    16384  1 r8169
snd                    73728  22 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
mei_me                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    81920  1 mei_me
shpchp                 32768  0
ie31200_edac           16384  0
thermal                20480  0
fan                    16384  0
battery                20480  0
tpm_infineon           20480  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    49152  3 tpm_infineon,tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi
video                  36864  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
button                 16384  0
ses                    20480  0
enclosure              16384  1 ses
scsi_transport_sas     36864  1 ses
usbip_host             28672  0
usbip_core             28672  1 usbip_host
crypto_user            16384  0
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
ext4                  557056  2
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                   90112  1 ext4
fscrypto               24576  1 ext4
sr_mod                 24576  0
cdrom                  53248  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 49152  9
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 45056  0
hid                   114688  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            65536  1 uas
ahci                   36864  6
libahci                28672  1 ahci
libata                208896  2 ahci,libahci
xhci_pci               16384  0
ehci_pci               16384  0
scsi_mod              155648  7 sd_mod,ses,usb_storage,scsi_transport_sas,libata,uas,sr_mod
xhci_hcd              188416  1 xhci_pci
ehci_hcd               73728  1 ehci_pci
usbcore               208896  10 usbhid,snd_usb_audio,usb_storage,usbip_host,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,snd_usbmidi_lib,uas,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
usb_common             16384  2 usbcore,usbip_core
serio                  20480  0
```

I can't think of what other kinds of information I can provide.

Comment: If it "spontanously" stopped working, that means it works with other versions of arch and/or other versions of Linux. Compare `dmesg` output after boot for working and non-working OS, see what's different.

Comment: I should have clarified that the other OS is Windows, which afaik doesn't have dmesg. It was likely a update but how can I confirm that? Easiest way to downgrade? Which package handles that? Guessing the kernel itself

Comment: If it's really the fault of the Arch kernel, I guess the simplest way would be to try with one (or several) USB stick image(s) you can boot from, e.g. [Debian](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/), or [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/). That assumes you have USB 2 ports that work. Otherwise try PXE network boot.

Comment: Inspecting `dmesg` from Arch after boot may already give hints, though.